# How can I make my background image be fully seen on a page

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to put a  background image in the center of the page, but the image goes out of the page and seen only partially.

This is my css code:

```
body{background-image:url(../img/music_palace_logo2.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
background-size:50%;
```

I tried to change background-size:

```
background-size:contain;
```

but it's makes the image too small.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
background-size: cover;
```

CSS rule.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/sobtwzgv/

```
html{
    background: url('http://www.vetprofessionals.com/catprofessional/images/home-cat.jpg') no-repeat 0 0 scroll;
    background-color:white;
    background-size: 50%;
    background-position:center;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use cover

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Before anyone chooses to [recommend deletion](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11110535) of this post, this is a valid attempted answer. This post should not have been flagged and should not be recommended for deletion in the LQPRQ. See: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563) and [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370)

Answer (score 0):

`background-size: 50%;` will set the size to 50% of the original

`background-size: contain;` will set the size to fit the entire image on the screen, leaving space along the side or bottom

`background-size: cover;` will fill the screen but could clip the bottom or side of the image

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 0):

If neither of the other suggestions work. You need to open the picture in Photoshop and expand it manually and then place it on your website. Regular images can be sized in html but when it comes to background images you have to be very accurate with the resolution you need. The good thing is you already called it, so all you have to do is change it and make sure it is saved in the same place with the same name and it should appear when you reload your web page.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.this works for me!
`body{
    background-image:url('image.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center;}`

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different from foreyez solution

[JS-Bin](https://jsbin.com/nuyoraredi/1/edit?css,output)

code

```
body {
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/3eRS4Nh.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;    
  background-size:50%;
}
```